# In Junit, how can I add individual test cases into a test suite?

Tags: java, testing, junit

In Junit 4.11, how can I select individual test cases from a test case class to add into a test suite? This allows me to select **some but not necessarily all** of the test cases defined in a test case class, to create and run.

For comparison, in JUnit 3.8, https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-extreme-programming/0596003870/ch04s08.html describes a way to add individual test cases into a test suite:

```
public class TestGame extends TestCase {
    ...
    public static Test suite(  ) {
               return new TestSuite(TestGame.class);
               }
}

public static Test suite(  ) {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(  );
    // To use this idiom, you must define the String constructor in your 
    // TestGame class. Remember that JUnit 3.8 made that constructor optional.
    suite.addTest(new TestGame("testCreateFighter"));
    suite.addTest(new TestGame("testSameFighters"));
    return suite;
}
```

Comment: In JUnit 4, the tests are configured via annotations. Check https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/aggregating-tests-in-suites

Comment: The link shows only adding all the test cases from a test case class into a test suite. It does not select some test cases, which is what I ask for

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in JUnit 4. The Suite class expects test classes. Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240475/junit4-creating-test-suite-with-specific-test-methods